# Why one parameter Ocaml function works with two arguments

Tags: function, parameters, arguments, ocaml

I can't understand why the following function works with 2 arguments even if we declare it with one param:

```
let rec removeFromList e = function
   h :: t -> if h=e then h 
             else h :: removeFromList e t
   | _ -> [];;

removeFromList 1 [1;2;3];;
```

Comment: **(1)** The function `removeFromList` won't compile, unless it's enclosed in some context containing some other definition of `removeFromList`. I believe the intention was to define it like this `let rec removeFromList ...`. **(2)** The compiler should complain about the missing `[]` case in the function's body.

Comment: thanks, i've written it wrong; edited so now it should be ok

Comment: *All* functions in OCaml always take exactly one argument. The syntax `removeFromList e t` (which parses as `(removeFromList e) t` because function application is left-associative) simply applies `removeFromList` to `e`, and then applies the result of that (which happens to be a function) to `t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring it with two parameters. The syntax:

```
let f = function ...
```

can be seen as a shortcut for

```
let f x = match x with
```

So, your definition is actually:

```
let rec removeFromList e lst = match lst with
  h :: t -> if h=e then h else h :: removeFromList e
```